# Why does the histogram look like that?

Tags: r, histogram

I feel like I should know this and like I have a knot in my brain.
I have data that looks like this:

there a scale going 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3 etc and for each scale point there's a certain number of people who selected it - none of the data points is 0.

Yet, the histogram looks like this with the weird spaces in between. Why?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add the code you tried. If you are not able to share your data, it would be helpful if you shared a similar fake example. See also this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: This is the code that I tried: ggplot(df.cs_overall, aes(x=cs_mean.score)) + 
geom_histogram(fill="#F0A9D7")

Comment: Without information on what your `df.cs_overall` contains, it is unfortunately a bit hard to reproduce your issue. Could you maybe add an excerpt (i.e. the one you get running `dput(head(df.cs_overall, 20))`) to your question?

Comment: cs_mean.score = c(6, 4.5, 5.75, 6, 4.5, 5.5, 4.5, 5.25, 7, 
    4, 6.5, 6, 4.75, 2.75, 5, 5.25, 5.75, 6, 5.25, 4.75) - the histogram only depicts this object from the dataframe - does that help?

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you just need to set your binwidth appropriately.
Here is an example using simulated data, first with the standard binwidth, second with a binwidth of .25:

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df.cs_overall <- tibble(cs_mean.score = sample(seq(0,5,.25), 500, T))


ggplot(df.cs_overall, aes(x=cs_mean.score)) + geom_histogram(fill="#F0A9D7")
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(df.cs_overall, aes(x=cs_mean.score)) + geom_histogram(fill="#F0A9D7", binwidth = .25)
```

[image]